# Hey! Why does that community guy get credit for my tag creation?

Tags: discussion, tags, community

As in, for example, [this tag](https://serverfault.com/posts/421534/revisions).

Is it because I don't have enough rep for tag-wiki edits without approval?  Not that it matters a whole lot, but it feels like something of a punch in the fun bits, and something of a disincentive to put the effort into creating a tag until I get more rep.

Is that intentional, or should that behavior be changed?

Comment: That community guy gets credit for everything. Also blame.

Comment: @voretaq7 When did we stop blaming **you** for everything?

Comment: @Ward I only accept the blame for the dead bodies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not looking at the tag, you're looking at the tag wiki. The Tag Wiki must be created by *someone*, and is created blank. Your wiki edits (which are awesome, by the way) are edits to the blank wiki.

My guess is because this is because when we approve edits to the wikis, it shows a diff between the two versions. And you can't show a diff unless there are two versions, so a blank Community one is created.

[image: Diff of a tag edit]

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize there was a distinction between the tag and the tag wiki.